# Having trouble getting my program to read a file from in_stream in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int NUMBER = 20;

void dataRead(double a[], int size, double& data);
double averageArray(const double a[], double data);
double totalArray(const double a[], double data);
double highCost(const double a[], double data);
double lowCost(const double a[], double data);

int main()
{
     // Calling in the file
     ifstream in;
     char in_file[16];
     double data;
     double averageSales, higherSale, lowerSale, totalSales, salesData[NUMBER];
     cout << "Enter the input file name." << endl;
     cin >> in_file;
     in.open(in_file);
    // Incase the file doesnt open
     if(in.fail())
{
    cout << "File not found." << endl;
    exit(1);
}
    // For calling the answers from the formula functions
     totalSales = totalArray(salesData, data);
     cout << endl << "The total sales are $" << totalSales << endl;
     averageSales = averageArray(salesData, data);
     cout << "The average sales amount is $" << averageSales << endl;
     higherSale = highCost(salesData, data);
     cout << "The highest sales amount is $" << higherSale << endl;
     lowerSale = lowCost(salesData, data);
     cout << "The lowest sales amount is $" << lowerSale << endl;
     return 0;
 }
     // Formula functions used for values
 double totalArray(const double sales[], double n)
 {
     double sum = 0;
     for(int count = 0; count < n; count++)
     sum += sales[count];
     return(sum);
 }

 double averageArray(const double sales[], double n)
 {
     return((double)totalArray(sales, n));
 }

 double highCost(const double sales[], double n)
 {
     double highest;
     highest = sales[0];
     for(int count = 1; count < n; count++)
     if(highest < sales[count])
     highest = sales[count];
     return(highest);
 }

double lowCost(const double sales[], double n)
{
    double lowest;
    lowest = sales[0];
    for(int count = 1; count < n; count++)
    if(lowest > sales[count])
    lowest = sales[count];
    return(lowest);
}

void readData(int a[], int size, double& data)
{
}
```

I am having trouble getting my program to read files and calculate the data for answers.. It is supposed to take in a file and return specific values pertaining to what is in the file. Like the average, highest cost value, lowest cost value, and total values together. I am compiling this on c9.io and when I added a new file to grab the information from no matter what values I put in the file it just gives me zeros or weird numbers with remainders. Would appreciate some guidance! Thank you!

Comment: Its not enough to open file, you need to read data from this file (being care about types), then you can run calculation functions.

Comment: You haven't added any code to read data from the input file. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: Im a little confused as to what Im adding, and a lot of confused as to where I would add it..

Comment: But to be honest your code is completely wrong at the moment and it looks like you want someone write it for you - this is not what SO is for.

Comment: What else is wrong other than it not reading the file?? I dont need someone to do it for me I am just a noob I just need tips.. I dont really want to start all over again I feel like most of this is decent.

Answer (score 0):

You open the file, but never read anything from it (nor close it, for that matter).  You read from `in` in a similar way that you read from `in`, and this describes how to close: [How to close IStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5158697/535275).

Comment: So I need to add something to read the file and then something to close it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a line that would actually read the data in the file, you're just opening it.

**How to read the contents of a file**

If your file has just plain numbers and whitespace in it, like "69 10 38 33 (...)", you'll want to read them like that:

```
int number;
file>>number;
cout<<number<<endl;

file>>number;
cout<<number<<endl;
```

- the example program will output the following:

```
69
10
```

When your file is written to be more "human-readable", like:

```
Value1 - 69
Value2 - 10
etc.
```

it gets tricky. I would recommend just changing the file to the " 69 10 ..." format. If you really want to keep it like that, you could read the values to a string - just as you would with numbers - and check if it's numerical. If yes, convert it to an int using stringstream. These 2 functions may help you

```
#include <sstream>

int StringToInt(string input)
{
    int res;
    stringstream ss(input);
    ss>>res;
    return res;
}

bool IsNumeric(string input)
{
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); i++)
    {
        if(input[i] < '0' && input[i] > '9')
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And by the way: you can't pass arrays to a function like you tried to do.